# A function coming as differentiable, though its not continuous

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    -x, &-1\le x<0\\
    1-x, &0\le x<1
  \end{cases}$$

Here each interval is continuous and differentiable in itself.

So only point to worry about is $x=0$

Let's check if $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$

$$f(0^-)=0,f(0^+)=1,f(0)=1$$

Hence function is not continuous at $x=0$.

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
    -1, &-1\le x<0\\
    -1, &0\le x<1
  \end{cases}$$

$$f'(0^+)=-1,f(0^-)=-1$$

Hence function is coming differentiable at $x=0$

What am I missing here:-

Answer (score 1):

The term $f'(0)$ is not necessarily equal to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f'(x)$ or $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}f'(x)$ unless that $f'$ is continuous at $0$.

But in this case, $f'$ doesn't exist at $0$, the reasoning is that,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{-h-1}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{-}}\left(-1-\dfrac{1}{h}\right),
\end{align*}
which doesn't exist.

Comment: I didn't assume $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, I assumed $f(x)$ is continuous in interval $[-1,0)$ which is actually true and $f(x)$ is continuous in interval $[0,1)$ which is actually true, so what is the issue in differentiating in these intervals?

Comment: I am saying the $f'$, not $f$.

Comment: Okay on those two intervals, inside the points, they are good, you can do the differentiation as usual, but as you have noticed that, the point $0$ needs to be taken special care, that you cannot differentiate the endpoint of the intervals as usual.

Comment: or we can adopt the practice of checking continuity first , then this will work right?

Comment: Of course you can do that, but you also see the difference quotient has no limit, which provides another way to say the non-existence of the derivative at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-1}{h}
$$
does not exist

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Of course this function isn't differentiable at $0$ just because the derivative is constant on $(-1,1)$.

Comment: sorry, off the topic question, what you use for plotting graphs?

Comment: @user3290550 That's Geogebra.